# How to get the Quote Name displayed in a visual force page

Tags: visualforce, quote

Can any one help me out on this .I would like get the Quote Name displayed in visual force page.It just Displays the users name ,the quote name doesnt get displayed.Any suggestion plz.

**Visualforce Code:**

```
<apex:page standardController="Quote">
  <apex:pageBlock title="Hello {!$User.FirstName}!">
<P>You are viewing the {!Quote.Name} </p>
</apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page
```

Comment: @SF_user:i used the {!$Quote.Name},but it throws an Error: Field $Quote.Name does not exist

Answer (score 3):

The `$` is definitely not used here; `$User` is just a special globally available mergefield.
I think you may have better results if you display that second line using an `apex:outputField` instead of a `<P>` tag, like so

```
<apex:outputField value="You are viewing the {!Quote.Name}" />
```

Check out [this documentation on working with standard controllers](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Building_Visualforce_Pages_Using_the_Standard_Controller#CONTROLLING_DATA) for more example and information.